# Tikk Sound at the Start of the Voice with handsfree on ubuntu

Tags: pipewire

At the beginning of the sound with handsfree، a doop sound is played.

I use PipeWire.

Speaker is good.

```
Audio:
 Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
 Device-2: Intel 8 Series HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
 API: ALSA v: k6.6.15-amd64 status: kernel-api
 Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.3 status: active
```

Comment: Are you sure that sound effect is not hardcoded into the other device?

Comment: Yes. Just with handsfree. Doop or Tikk

Comment: Oh. I'm so sorry, I use PipeWire